Let the digits $a, b, c$ be in A.P. Nine digit numbers are to be formed with following restrictions. How many such numbers can be formed?
Let the digits $a, b, c$ (non-zero and distinct) be in A.P. Nine-digit numbers are to be formed using each of these three digits thrice such that three consecutive digits are in non- constant A.P. at least once. How many such numbers can be formed?
I figured out that they want permutations of $aaabbbccc$ such that it must contain atleast one of the following groups atleast once:
$abc, cba.$
But how to proceed? I have tried using principle of inclusion and exclusion but nothing has worked out. Please guide me through this.
